# Run mlagents_envs UnityEnvironment from remote ssh login

Tags: python-3.x, unity-game-engine, ubuntu, terminal, glx

I have a script in which I build a `mlagents_envs.environments.UnityEnvironment` that successfully launches and works when I run the script from terminal sessions started on my ubuntu machine (that has a GUI). And if I ssh into the machine, I can run these scripts from tmux sessions that were originally created locally on my machine. If, however, I try to run the script from a terminal session created through the remote ssh connection, the script hangs when trying to create the `UnityEnvironment`. It just says:

```
Found path: <path_to_unity_executable>
```

and eventually times out.

I've tried to run the script with a virtual display and it still doesn't work. Specifically, I've tried:

```
$ xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args='-screen 1 640x480x24:64' python3 python_script.py -batchmode

$ xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args='-screen 1 640x480x24:64' python3 python_script.py
```

And I've tried the instructions found here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Training-on-Amazon-Web-Service.md

Has anyone encountered this issue? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being fairly simple. I just needed to specify the right DEVICE before running the script.

```
$ DEVICE=:1 python3 python_script.py
```

If anyone else runs into this, you might also need to enable X11 forwarding in both the ssh settings on the server and the client. I'm not 100% sure.